# How to display Shapefile in SilverLight With EsriMap and get the cordinate from Sql Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, silverlight, shapefile, esri

I won't to create website that display offline shapefile into silverlight and get the latitude and longitude from sql server

Answer (score 0):

The following library provides shapefile loading for the esri API: http://esrislcontrib.codeplex.com/

Your description of SQL server is pretty unclear but anything from a server you would need to build a service for. My blog post here gives you some hints to get started with that: http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/03/11/sending-geometry-between-silverlight-and-the-server-using-wcf/

Comment: I have Gis device connect with Sql server i wont to Get x and y and add marker to shape file